# Proof writing that $d_{A}^{-1}(0)=\bar{A}$, $d_{A} : X → \mathbb{R}, d_{A}(x) := \inf \{d(x, a) : a \in A\}.$

Tags: analysis, continuity

Proof that $d_{A}^{-1}(0)=\bar{A}$,  $d_{A} : X → \mathbb{R}, d_{A}(x) := \inf \{d(x, a) : a \in A\}.$

My new tutor has complaint that my proofs make no sense, are poorly structured, are full mistakes, use wrong definitions, the notation is wrong and the task is not understood properly in the first place.

$\bar{A} \subset d_{A}^{-1}(0)$.

In order to show this we need to show that for all $a \in A$ we find that $d_{A}(a)=0$. Assume $A$ is open. If $a \in A$ we simply choose $x=a$ in the definition of $d_{A}(x)$ thus $d_{A}(x)=0$. Assume $A$ is closed. If $a$ is not part of $\partial A$ we simply choose $x=a$ in the definition of $d_{A}(x)$ thus $d_{A}(x)=0$. If $a$ is part of the boundary we know that we can construct a sequence $a_n$ which converge to $a$. Thus since the sequence converges $\inf \{d(a, a_n) : a \in A\}=0$.

$d_{A}^{-1}(0)  \subset \bar{A}$

Let $y \in d_{A}^{-1}(0)$. Then it holds true that there exists a sequence $a_n$ such that $d(y,a_n)=0$ for some $a \in A$. Thus $y \in \bar{A}$

What could be done to improve this?